# Where the following code creating forlder

Tags: android, file, directory

kindly guide me where the following code is creating folder? i didnt find it.
and i also wanted to know about this function [getExternalStorageDirectory()] that  what location it returns in sd card?

```
MY_IMG_DIR = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/.Plsys/");
```

Answer (score 1):

Folder is created in sdcard but got hidden Because Your foldername start with dot(.).**Dont use the dot**.
Hope it will help.

Comment: MY_IMG_DIR = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Plsys/");  this will allow you to see file "Plsys" inside your sdcard.

Comment: actually i want to do is, to show all images from internal and external memory in an activity. plz help

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the developer refrence of the Android API [Android API Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns the root of your "external" storage. Combining this with your string it should return something like "`/storage/emulated/0/.Plsys`" or similar. Just logcat the file and you wil get a direct path string.

As @user2527725 stated right directories with a dot(.) in front will be hidden on Android.

Comment: thnx dear. i want to place images in .Plsys so that images are accessible from gallery. so plz guide me how i show all images in my app's activity and then move selected images to .Plsys